# Get count on the base of column from laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a collection and I grouped them based on cities.

```
$collection = Order::with([
            'orderItems',
            'customer'
        ])->get();

$batches = $collection->groupBy('cities');

$mumbai = $batches->get('membai')
```

In each group of a collection like $mumbai, I have a column "status", I want to get its count like numbers of orders having the status "delivered", "pending" etc. How can I do this? Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: did u find answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it that way:

```
$collection = Order::groupBy('group_id')
->selectRaw('count(*) as total, group_id')
->get();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To **count** column by **case when**

So you can get all that count of status in one grouped record.

I think you can do something like this.

```php
$collection = Order::with([
            'orderItems',
            'customer'
        ])->groupBy('cities')
          ->select(\DB::raw('
               SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN status = "delivered" THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
               END) AS delivered_count,
               SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN status = "pending" THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                   END) AS pending_count
            '), 'membai')->get();
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: @Harris Khan Did you try the code or find the answer?